# Why doesn't this JavaScript work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, form-submit

```
<form action="http://google.com">
  <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:this.disabled='disabled';return true">
</form>
```

It works in Firefox, but not in IE8, Safari (It should forward me to Google's site, it but doesn't happen.). Why?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean.  What error message is in the console.  Or what behaviour are you seeing.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840742/disable-a-button-on-click http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106509/disable-button-on-form-submission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled='disabled';form.submit()">
```

**Edit:** Added `form.` as per wamp's comment.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to be something with IE's implementation of JavaScript.

Comment: Probably more accurately, it's likely a problem with IE's implementation of the *DOM*.  Or maybe this is relying on an extension, because I don't remember any global `submit` functions.

Comment: In some cases, I need `form.submit()`, simply `submit` will get an error saying "Object expected",strange..

Comment: @strager,you are right,the global `submit` doesn't work in my application,but works in this simplified example,this is strange..

Comment: @wamp - `submit()` only worked when I tested it, but just to be on the safe side, I added the `form.` from your comment.

Comment: @strager - I tested it in IE 8, Firefox and Iron. Anyway, I've changed the code in my example above.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the javascript: pseudoprotocol. This should work:

```
onclick="this.disabled=true"
```

and you don't need to return true, that'll happen automatically.